# Can't set Password for Postgres using docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, yaml, docker-compose

I am not able to set Password for Postgres using Docker-compose. Postgres is loading without password and with the default user name "postgres", non of the environment variables below seems to applied. below is the db service of my docker-compose.yml file: (version 3)

```
db:
  image: postgres
  container_name: postgres
  environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_DB: db
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
    - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

Note I tried using the "-POSTGRES_USER=" as well, it didn't work

Also, I deleted all old containers/volumes.

Any idea?

Comment: login permissions are set in the pg_hba.conf file.

Comment: Is there a pg_hba.conf file in the shared volume folder ./postgres-data?

Answer (score 24):

The problem should be with the volume attached. When your container start it will add the credentials you give him, but then the volume will be attached and that will cause this information being rewritten.

For more information have a look at  https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/203#issuecomment-255200501.

Comment: HI @FrankerZ thanks for your feedback. I just expend to give the relevant information. let me know if you think this answer is more appropriate.

Comment: Yup, problem is the volume. I simply changed my volume name and it accepted the new credentials.

Answer (score 16):

The main reason being use of ':' instead of "=" in the environment section.
Ideally it should look like this:

```
db:
  image: postgres
  container_name: postgres
  environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD= pass
      - POSTGRES_DB= db
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
    - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

Comment: Why does this matter?

Answer (score 4):

Your configuration works fine for me.  I suspect you are not using the complete set of correct credentials, which includes the username, password, *and database name*.  If I take your example `docker-compose.yaml` and run it without modifications, I can connect to the database `db` like this with username `user` and password `pass`:

```
$ psql -h localhost -U user db
Password for user user: 
psql (9.5.7, server 9.6.1)
WARNING: psql major version 9.5, server major version 9.6.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

db=#
```

Answer (score 2):

Just run

```
docker compose down -v
```

then do the

```
docker compose up
```

*Warning - First Command will erase your volume

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
Couldn't solve it for 2 weeks.
Read almost everything related to it.

And after I finished all PosgreSQL server related processes on local machine, everything goes well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33777807)

Answer (score 0):

Have you deleted the volumes as well?

Try this:

```bash
docker stop $(docker ps -qa) && docker rm $(docker ps -qa) && docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

Resource:
https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/542#issuecomment-271898987

Answer (score -1):

Start postgres instance:-

> docker run --name postgres-0 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword -p 5433:5433 -d postgres

Now we can check docker all running container by this command:-

> docker ps

Comment: This is related to Dockerfile, not docker-compose. Downvote.